# Small question about convergence

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I have a small question: if i have that $$\int_0^{+\infty}p(t)|u'_n(t)-u'(t)|^2dt\rightarrow 0$$

is it true that $$\int_0^{+\infty} p(t)|u'_n(t)|^2 dt\rightarrow \int_0^{+\infty} p(t)|u'(t)|^2 dt $$

for a positive function $p$ such that $\frac1p\in L^1((0,+\infty))$

Please help me

Thank you.

Comment: What space are the $u_n,u$ in and what do you mean by $u_n \to u$?

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Is there some significance to the prime on the $u$s and what space do they lie in? If $u_n' = u'$ then the top integral is trivially zero, but the others need not even be defined.

Comment: *Small* question. Seems appropriate given that you're talking about convergence ;)

Answer (score 1):

**hint:**

$$||a | -|b| | \leq |a-b|. $$

Comment: this don't give me the answer !

Comment: ??????????????????